# Implement only one method from interface in anonymous class

Tags: java, kotlin

Is it possible in Kotlin to create an anonymous class implementing a certain interface and only implement the functions you'll need? For example I want to create a class implementing `AnimationListener` which has 3 methods:

- onAnimationStart
- onAnimationEnd
- onAnimationRepeat

If I only want to use the `onAnimationEnd` callback, can I just do something like this?

```
object : AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationEnd() {
        //my implementation
    }
}
```

The way I've done this in Java was by creating a class which implemented the interface, just create anonymous class of that class and override the methods I need.
I was hoping Kotlin has a better, less verbose, approach on this.

Comment: It's `implementing` an interface method and not overriding it !

Comment: Related: [Can I omit the interface methods I do not use in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362581/can-i-omit-the-interface-methods-i-do-not-use-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't expect there's anything in Kotlin different to Java in this respect. You can, however, create your own interfaces that have default no-op implementation of methods you don't need :

```
interface AnimationEndListener : AnimationListener {
  fun onAnimationStart() {}
  fun onAnimationRepeat() {}
}
```

Then actual concrete implementation will extend `AnimationEndListener` and override only what's needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave this open for now, in case other people would provide a different answer or workaround. But for now, this seems to be the way to go

Comment: There's [`AnimationListenerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html) which allows to do what OP asks for.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks for this, this is something I'll be able to use, but this was just an example. I was looking for a general answer

Comment: @azizbekian, `Adapter` is a class though, while `AnimationListener` is supposed to be an interface. Approach with specialized interfaces in Java ecosystem is more preferrable, I feel, as that creates `FunctionalInterface`s - valid targets for lambda generation.